# How to download an entire site with wget including its images

Tags: shell, wget

I'm trying to download an entire site with `wget` like this:

`wget -r http://whatever/`

`wget -m http://whatever/`

But it only downloads the pages with text, no images. How can I download the pages with text and images? What am I missing here?

Comment: technically http is part of the url so it'd be more accurate to replace `http://url.url.url` with `http://whatever`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `wget` command you'll need to use is much lengthier as explained below. As such, you may wish to commit it to a file like `wholesite.sh`, make it an executable, and run it. It'll create a directory of the url and subdirectories of the site's assets, including images, js, css, etc.

```
wget \
     --recursive \
     --level 5 \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --adjust-extension \
     --span-hosts \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains yoursite.com \
     --no-parent \
         yoursite.com
```

#### Explanation

`--recursive`  This specifies how many subdirectories of the site's assets you want to retrieve(since assets like images are often kept in subdirectories of the site) The default max depth to search for assets is 5 subdirectories. You can modify this with the `level` flag just below.

`--level 5` Search through 5 subdirectories for assets. I'd recommend increasing or decreasing this if the target site is larger or smaller respectively.

`--no-clobber`  Don't overwrite existing files.

`--page-requisites`  causes `wget` to download all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page which includes **images**, css, js, etc.

`--adjust-extension`  Preserves proper file extensions for .html, .css, and other assets.

`--span-hosts`  Include necessary assets from offsite as well.

`--convert-links`  Update site links to work as files within subdirectories on your local machine(for viewing locally).

`--restrict-file-names=windows`  Modify filenames to work in Windows as well, in case you're using this command on a Windows system.

`--domains yoursite.com`  Do not follow links outside this domain.

`--no-parent`  Don't follow links outside the directory you pass in.

`yoursite.com` # The URL to download

---

#### Example adapted from: https://gist.github.com/christiangenco/8531418

Comment: you're writing your own explanations.. but in a format that looks it might be copy/pasted from something official. You should be more clear. This is the official description for `-r`  `-r,  --recursive   specify recursive download`  And if it's infinitely recursive then probably nobody would use it without `-l` I know when i've used `-r` it as ALWAYS been used with `-l` and then it won't just download infinitely.  You seem to be suggesting `-r` alone, to download "a whole site".  But if that's infinite then perhaps that might not stop until your hard drive is stuffed with much of the internet?

Comment: Your assessment of recursive retrieving is fair. I figured the default max depth(for modern versions of GNU Wget) of 5 would be adequate for this user's needs. I've personally used versions of this command with more or fewer flags and in this case, I copied this from an online source to get a faster answer. I'll rewrite it to include more in-depth explanations.

Comment: when you say `--span-hosts Include necessary assets from offsite as well.`  Are you sure. Are you sure that won't actually when combined with your `-r -l 5` lead to all sorts of links that aren't relevant and are from other sites.  Necessary assets sounds like just images from elsewhere. But spanning sites do a depth of -r -l 5 could go way more. I'm not sure how one would ensure wget gets pages recursively when local, but for necessary assets like images, when going off site, how one would make it not  go recursive?

Comment: And if you don't follow links outside your domain, then will it still  get necessary assets like images.   Maybe it will work.. but have you tested it?  I might try it some time, it sounds interesting  The wget --help just says ` -D,  --domains=LIST              comma-separated list of accepted domains`  so doesn't say specifically following links but may be more general.. so i'm not sure it will still get images off site maybe it will.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.`-D` restricts downloading assets too. You can add the CDNs manually, so wget will only download images/css/etc from these domains, and won't follow links to other domains, but that's all.

Comment: That command list didn't work for me. I removed the windows file name restriction, but doubt impacted (I am on Linux). Just downloaded the single index.html file no matter how modified the domain target. Decided just try wget --recursive https://target.com/subdirofinterest/ and vacuumed the entire site (didn't realize recurse would proceed back up the folder hierarchy), including all images, pdf, you name it. Stopped it after quarter gig downloaded, but got what I wanted, among many, many other things, grin.